# When adding other language string content into a PHP file, it prints special characters and PHP syntax errors occur

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to add Sinhala language content into my CodeIgniter website. I use language file to retrieve data. In my language file when I paste Sinhala language content into my editor, It looks like lots of special characters and it not readable.

The problem is that it contains semicolons and single quotations. But actual document not contain semicolons or single quotation marks. So that it occurs PHP syntax errors.

```
$lang['hystry_para5'] = "flfkl= l=rK hehso ;jfll= lgqkdhl hehso wu";
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set your text editor to save this file as a UTF-8 file.

For Sinhala, you can use the following web service to make your text UTF-8:

http://www.ucsc.cmb.ac.lk/ltrl/services/feconverter/?maps=s_tbs-u.xml

Comment: I am using php storm IDE. I set it into utf-8. But it still same problem.

Comment: Maybe try using this service? http://www.ucsc.cmb.ac.lk/ltrl/services/feconverter/?maps=s_tbs-u.xml

Comment: Can you please edit your answer with link and with more details.The answer looks like comment.